# im trying to make a program for counting how many years will it take for people to a rubix cube

Tags: python

I am working on a program that will count how many years will it take for 6M + 5 each day to solve a rubix cube.
Here is my code so far:

```
def yearsTime():
    
    scrambles = 43252003274489856000
    cubers = 6000000
    #basic info

    def cubersCount():
        cubers = cubers + 5
        #it cannot detect the cuber amount, and i dont know why because its above this function.
    scrambles = scrambles / 25
    scrambles = scrambles / 24
    scrambles = scrambles / 60
    scrambles = scrambles / 24
    scrambles = scrambles / 365
    #year counter and other things (not the problem)
    print(scrambles)
    #does what it tells


yearsTime()
```

I want the cubers function to add 5 every 24 hours, how can I do that?

Comment: Why did you define `cubersCount()` as a nested function?  Was that intentional?

Comment: @JohnGordon Let me edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function only does cubers += 5, then i don't think its needed. but to answer your question, if you want to modify a variable that is in the outer function nest, you have to declare it in the inner nest as nonlocal first.

```
def yearsTime():
    
    scrambles = 43252003274489856000
    cubers = 6000000
    #basic info

    def cubersCount():
        nonlocal cubers
        cubers = cubers + 5
```

as for what you are trying to do, it is not clear. it seem a mathematical problem, for example the rate of solving cubes will change for every 5 people added, so what is the solving rate of each person? is it only one scramble per person? if so you only need a loop that will minus the amount of people "multiplied by solving rate" from the amount of scrambles, if i understand it correctly per day.
for example:

```
def yearsTime():

scrambles = 43252003242342
cubers = 6000000
days = 0
while True:
    scrambles -= cubers
    days += 1
    cubers += 5

    if scrambles <= 0:
        break

print(days)
```

yearsTime()